# Form validate not working properly

Tags: java, javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to make a validate form. I can't get my validate form to work properly the phone function is not working and I'm not sure if it's just submitting it even if the user press submit, could anyone help me?

html:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" name="formValidation">
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br /><br />
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br /><br />
    <label>E_mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" onchange="validateEmail(this.value)"/><br /><br />
    <label>Confirm E_mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="confirmEmail" onchange="validateEmail(this.value)"/><br /><br />
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Address" /><br /><br />
    <label>Telephone nr:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fld" /><br /><br />
    <br />
    <p>submit your form: </p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

js:

```
function validate(){
    if(document.formValidation.firstName.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.lastName.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.Email.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.confirmEmail.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.Address.value == "" ||
    document.formValidation.fld.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please fill all the boxes before submitting!");
        return false;
    } else if (telPhone(document.formValidation.fld.value)!=""){
        alert(error)
        return false
    }else {

        alert('Your form has been submitted!');
    }

}
function validateEmail(Email)   
{  
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(Email))  
  {  
    return true;  
  }  
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")  
    return (false) 
}

function telPhone(fld) {
    var error = "";
   if (fld == "") {
        error = "You didn't enter a phone number.";
    } else if (isNaN(fld)) {
        error = "The phone number contains illegal characters.";
    } else if (fld.length != 10) {
        error = "The phone number is the wrong length. Make sure you included an area code."
    }

    return error;
}
```

Comment: I get the error {"error": "Please use POST request"} . Should you not be using the following in the FORM tag action="http://example.com/" method="POST"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" name="formValidation"  action="fileto redirect here" method="post">
```